# IValueConverter parameter check

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Im using IValueConverter to set a checkbox.
But I have three checkbox and Im using like a RadioButton. When one is selected the anothers need to be uncheck.

So I did something like that>

```
<MenuItem StaysOpenOnClick="True" 
          Header="Reiniciar áudio"
          IsCheckable="True"
          Name="RestartAudioCheck" 
          IsChecked="{Binding PlayType, 
          Mode=TwoWay,
          Converter={StaticResource PlayTypeCheckedConverter},
          ConverterParameter=restart}">
</MenuItem>
<MenuItem StaysOpenOnClick="True" 
          Header="Parar áudio"
          IsCheckable="True"
          Name="StopAudioCheck"
          IsChecked="{Binding PlayType, 
            Mode=TwoWay,
          Converter={StaticResource PlayTypeCheckedConverter},
          ConverterParameter=stop}">
</MenuItem>
<MenuItem StaysOpenOnClick="True" 
          Header="Pausar áudio"
          IsCheckable="True"
          Name="PauseAudioCheck"
          IsChecked="{Binding PlayType, 
            Mode=TwoWay,
          Converter={StaticResource PlayTypeCheckedConverter},
          ConverterParameter=pause}">
</MenuItem>
```

And converter:

```
class PlayTypeCheckedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is PlayType type))
            return false;

        if (!(parameter is string check))
            return false;

        if (check.CompareTo("restart") == 0 && type == PlayType.Restart)
            return true;
        if (check.CompareTo("stop") == 0 && type == PlayType.Stop)
            return true;
        if (check.CompareTo("pause") == 0 && type == PlayType.Pause)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is bool isChecked))
            return true;

        if (!(parameter is string type))
            return PlayType.Restart;

        if (type.CompareTo("restart") == 0 && isChecked)
            return PlayType.Restart;
        if (type.CompareTo("stop") == 0 && isChecked)
            return PlayType.Stop;
        if (type.CompareTo("pause") == 0 && isChecked)
            return PlayType.Pause;

        return PlayType.Restart;
    }
}
```

My question is: its wrong to pass a ConverterParameter like a absolute text as the example to know something on converter? 
Like I did works very well.

Comment: why are you using a IvalueCOnverter, just bind the 3 checkbox with 3 differents values and play with in code behind or in view model. you could use mouse down event. or i misunderstand something....?

Comment: I haven't 3 different values to each checkbox. So, when Pause Type = Restart, the others checkbox will uncheck automatically and I did this ValueConverter to 3 checkbox

Comment: Why don't you just use a RadioButton instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explicitly compare string literals, like you did, is considered a bad practice in general. WPF or not, for obvious reasons that it is prone to runtime errors and no type checking exists.

There are two solutions I could think of:

1. The most common way would be to add three properties in the View Model with just getters that basically return true or false, if the state is satisfied. You can then raise property changed for all these three boolean properties when the Play State changes.

From this Example of the View Model, you could bind to each checkbox in the view their respective properties (`IsPlaying`,`IsStopped`,`IsPaused`) :

```
    private State _playState;
    public State PlayState
    {
        get { return _playState; }
        set {

            SetProperty(ref _playState, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsPlaying));
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsPaused));
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsStopped));
        }
    }

    public bool IsPlaying
    {
        get { return _playState == State.Playing; }
    }
    public bool IsPaused
    {
        get { return _playState == State.Paused; }
    }
    public bool IsStopped
    {
        get { return _playState == State.Stopped; }
    }
```

2. Use a `DataTrigger` in your XAML for checkboxes on your PlayState property. You can then check for typed enumeration values instead of string literals.

Comment: I'll try. In my head, when I did the code, I tried  to save code to reuse the converter. Thanks! Its a nice solution

Comment: Hey, @Ladder. I need to call three OnPropertyChanged each checkbox, am I right?

Comment: on the backing property. edited my post with an example

Comment: Exactly like I did. Thanks! And a question: dont have problem call more than one property changed in only one setter? I mean, its not a bad practice?

Comment: You're using the same backing field, _playState, for all the four properties. It's ok

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to have a single equality converter for any property type. The trick of using it is to pass parameters of specific type, instead of string representation.

the converter:

```
public class EqualityCheckConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Equals(value, parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (Equals(value, true))
            return parameter;

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

example with `enum`:

```
// property to bind
public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }
```

binding:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <wpfDemos:EqualityCheckConverter x:Key="EqualCheckedConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Menu>
    <MenuItem StaysOpenOnClick="True" 
              Header="Tuesday"
              IsCheckable="True"
              IsChecked="{Binding Day, 
              Mode=TwoWay,
              Converter={StaticResource EqualCheckedConverter},
              ConverterParameter={x:Static system:DayOfWeek.Tuesday}}"/>

    <MenuItem StaysOpenOnClick="True" 
              Header="Wednesday"
              IsCheckable="True"
              IsChecked="{Binding Day, 
              Mode=TwoWay,
              Converter={StaticResource EqualCheckedConverter},
              ConverterParameter={x:Static system:DayOfWeek.Wednesday}}"/>

    <MenuItem StaysOpenOnClick="True" 
              Header="Thursday"
              IsCheckable="True"
              IsChecked="{Binding Day, 
              Mode=TwoWay,
              Converter={StaticResource EqualCheckedConverter},
              ConverterParameter={x:Static system:DayOfWeek.Thursday}}"/>
</Menu>
```

---

example with `int`

```
public int TestNum { get; set; }
```

```
<Window.Resources>
    <wpfDemos:EqualityCheckConverter x:Key="EqualCheckedConverter"/>
    <system:Int32 x:Key="Zero">0</system:Int32>
    <system:Int32 x:Key="Ten">10</system:Int32>
</Window.Resources>
<Menu>
    <MenuItem StaysOpenOnClick="True" 
              Header="0"
              IsCheckable="True"
              IsChecked="{Binding TestNum, 
              Mode=TwoWay,
              Converter={StaticResource EqualCheckedConverter},
              ConverterParameter={StaticResource Zero}}"/>

    <MenuItem StaysOpenOnClick="True" 
              Header="10"
              IsCheckable="True"
              IsChecked="{Binding TestNum, 
              Mode=TwoWay,
              Converter={StaticResource EqualCheckedConverter},
              ConverterParameter={StaticResource Ten}}"/>
</Menu>
```

Comment: It's a nice solution. I didn't know about static parameters using enum. I will search more. Thanks for sharing.